# strtok() analogue in C++

Tags: c++, c, delimiter

I just can't find an algorithm to split the string into words by numerous delimiters. I know how to split a string by whitespace with `istringtream` and by **single delimiter** with `getline`. How can I connect them all.

For instance:

**input**: `This -is-a!,string;`
**output**:

```
This  
is  
a  
string
```

Comment: You'll probably find one in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Comment: You can use regex with the std library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: There's also [Boost.tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void SplitToVector(vector<string> &v, string dlm, string src){
    string::size_type p, start=0, len=src.length(); 

    v.clear();
    start = src.find_first_not_of(dlm);
    p = src.find_first_of(dlm, start);
    while(p != string::npos){
        v.push_back(src.substr(start, p-start));
        start = src.find_first_not_of(dlm, p);
        p = src.find_first_of(dlm, start);
    }
    if(len>start)//rest
        v.push_back(src.substr(start, len - start));
}

int main(void){
    char input[256] = "This -is-a!,string;";
    vector<string> v;
    int i, size;

    SplitToVector(v, "-!,;", input);
    //cout << input << endl;
    size = v.size();
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        cout << v.at(i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `#include <cstring>` and use `std::strtok()` in your C++ program?

Comment: I'd like to use only C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend split in boost (string algorithm), see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp163440592.

Comment: You see, I'm using it for my exams, so it's not recommended to use external libraries.